# Is it possible to see what version of .NET an assembly was built in?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I don't need to do it from code or anything.  Just need to find out from windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

For example if you open log4net in reflector, you can see it's Target Runtime.

[image]

PS: BTW this new upload image feature is really cool

Comment: +1 for being the first to tell me about new upload image feature!

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily find out without checking dependencies.

You can use [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to do that.